# Unbound module Yojson.Basic.Util

Tags: makefile, build, functional-programming, ocaml

I try opening `Yojson.Basic.Util` in one of my files and keep getting an u`nbound module` error. I've tried several different things and can't seem to figure out what's wrong

I have this in my `.ocamlinit`:

```
#require "yojson";;
#require "ANSITerminal";;
```

and this in my `makefile`:

```
test:
    ocamlbuild -pkg yojson, oUnit test.byte && ./test.byte

play:
    ocamlbuild -pkgs oUnit,yojson,str,ANSITerminal main.byte && ./main.byte

check:
    bash checkenv.sh

clean:
    ocamlbuild -clean
```

Typing `make` produces this error:

```
ocamlbuild -pkg yojson, oUnit test.byte && ./test.byte
ocamlfind: Package `yojson,' not found
Cannot run Ocamlfind.
make: *** [test] Error 2
```

Changing the `makefile` to:

```
test:
    ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind -pkg yojson, oUnit test.byte && ./test.byte

play:
    ocamlbuild -pkgs oUnit,yojson,str,ANSITerminal main.byte && ./main.byte

check:
    bash checkenv.sh

clean:
    ocamlbuild -clean
```

I type in `make` and it gives me this error:

```
ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind -pkg yojson, oUnit test.byte && ./test.byte
Solver failed:
  Ocamlbuild knows of no rules that apply to a target named oUnit. This can happen if you ask Ocamlbuild to build a target with the wrong extension (e.g. .opt instead of .native) or if the source files live in directories that have not been specified as include directories.
Compilation unsuccessful after building 0 targets (0 cached) in 00:00:00.
make: *** [test] Error 6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between the `-pkg` and `-pkgs` option for ocamlbuild. The `-pkg` option takes exactly one package name. The `-pkgs` option takes a list of comma-separated package names (there can be optional spaces before and after the commas, but then you have to quote the argument).

In your example, you use `-pkg`, but with a comma-separated list of arguments, and that list has a space, so it would have to be quoted. Using `-pkgs yojson,oUnit` should fix the issue.